# SharePoint Error Invalid look-up value. A look-up field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, lookup-column

While trying to update a value in pages library, I am getting below error:

```
Invalid look-up value.

A look-up field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again.
```

This is happening for documents which are migrated from different environment..

Did anyone face this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open the documents and check the Document Information Panel. I suspect you will either need to clear the properties or correct all the lookup values for the new environment.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the list was saved as template and then migrated over to a separate tenant. As you noticed on creating a lookup field, it ask you on what field to a list you want to look up, that means, its tying up a property to another list to associate both list, having said that, saving the list as template won't include the associated list in the saved template, you need also to save the other list as template right?.

So now when the template has been migrate to another site, then when you create the list from the template you uploaded, the lookup field now is messed up cause it will some kind want to refresh what list it is trying to lookup to,

what i suggest is go to the lookup column and re associate it with desired lookup value, most of the time you may need to recreate the lookup field.

Let me know if I somehow shed at least a little insights,

Happy learning!